# In how many ways can 10 identical laptops be distributed among five electronic stores

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can 10 identical laptops be distributed among five electronic stores if

1. there are no restrictions?
2. each store gets at least one?
3. the largest store gets at least three?
4. each store gets at least two?

Would I used the r-combination with repetition for part 1?
so for part 1 you do$\binom{14}{10}$

I am learning r-combination and r-permutation and now I keep getting confused when given a problem

Comment: 1) Stars and Bars; 2) give one to each, then distribute $5$, Stars and Bars; 3) Give the big store $3$ then distribute the remaining $7$, Stars and Bars; 4) Joke question.

Comment: @Csci319 Your answer for part 3 is correct.

Comment: so I know each store needs to get 2 computers and now I need to figure out how many ways you can distribute 10 computers to 5 stores

Comment: @AndréNicolas there is only one way. $\binom{4}{4}=1$

Comment: We are distributing $0$ computers among $5$ stores. Depending on which formula you use, there are $\binom{4}{0}$ or $\binom{4}{4}$ ways to do it. But we don't need a formula, there is only $1$ way to distribute $0$ computers among $5$ stores.